# How can I code an adaptive/dynamic UILabel in iOS Swift/Obj-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I tried drawing it with CGRectMake + adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth, it gets it to work but only until if I need to size my UILabel less than 'default system font size' (i.e. 16 maybe), it doesn't get bigger more than 'default system font size'. On the other hand, if I hard code that font size like `UIFont(name: "any-font", size: 20)` it just keep stick to 20, no matter screen size decreases or increases. I also tried using `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2)` it gets it done, but it just zooms the text and make the quality poor it's rather a tedious way. How can i use a particular font size and make it adaptive/dynamic?

```
label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x + self.view.bounds.width * 0.2, self.view.bounds.origin.y + self.view.bounds.height * 0.2, self.view.bounds.width * 0.6, self.view.bounds.height * 0.2))
label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
label.text = "Sign in"
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.sizeToFit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
label.minimumFontSize    = 5.0;
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
```

Comment: Minimum Font Size deprecated on ios version 6.0 :D but still _minimumScaleFactor = 0.5_ worked, thanks mate.